# Objective C storing table rows count in variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I'm attempting to store the number of rows in a uitable into a variable (unsuccessfully), i tried this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
 NSNumber *rowsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section])];
 NSLog(@"%i", rowsNumber);
 return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

This is not working and only logs a 6 digit number? Can anyone hazard a guess how i could store this?

Comment: are you just trying to store [sectionInfo numberOfObjects] into rowsNumber?

Comment: Yes, thats what i'm trying to do

Comment: OK, then Yuji just answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't automatically convert non-objects and objects. (i.e. it doesn't "auto-box".)

Furthermore, the format specifier `%i` is *not* an unbox specification. So, if you have an `NSNumber*num`, you either do

```
NSLog(@"%@",num) // show as an object
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%d",[num intValue]) // show as an int.
```

This line is incorrect, too:

```
NSNumber *rowsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] ];
```

First of all, `[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section]` is an object which you just got in

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
```

You can't pass it to `numberWithInt:`. You obtain the number of rows using `sectionInfo.numberOfObjects`. So, the line should be

```
NSNumber *rowsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:sectionInfo.numberOfObjects];
```